# Simple jQuery DIV-based Menu

Tags: jquery, menu

my main problem is if i try too navigate to the sub-nav the background slide up and don't stay down.

here is the JSFiddle-Snippet: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9UaRL/

Short description for anybody who get a little bit into the code :)

-> When hover over main-nav-btn (DEMO 1, DEMO 2, DEMO 3) then a "main-sub" (div-container) appear.
-> HERE'S THE CATCH: if i navigate down, so that i'm inside the "main-sub" after the time i set the container slide up and dont stay down. WHY?

I'm open for all your suggestions the only thing is i want to have these button-tags for building the menu...

Thanks for your help.

Here's the jquery-code anyway can't pass the "links 2 jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code......

```
$(".main-nav-btn").each(function(){
        var over = $(this);
        var ishovered = false;
        var getMainValue = $(this).data('value');
        var show = function() {
            ishovered = true;
            $(".main-sub").stop().animate({height: "toggle"}, 100, "linear");
            };
        var hide = function() {
                ishovered = false;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(ishovered === false){
                        $(".main-sub").stop().animate({height: "toggle"}, 100, "linear"); 
                        };
                    }, 100);
            }
        if(getMainValue != 'home') {
            over.hover(show, hide);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Because as soon as you stop hovering over the upper button (.main-nav-btn), the main-sub must hide. So you're going to have to extend the hover function to the drop-down, or you'll have to hide the dropdown with a different function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated. See this [fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/alexela8882/Sxah8/19/)

You might love this...

```
<div id="menu-wrap" >
<div id="menu" >
    <ul>
        <li id="home-btn" >home</li>
        <li id="demo1-btn" >demo1</li>
        <li id="demo2-btn" >demo2</li>
        <li id="demo3-btn" >demo3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-drop1" ></div>
<div id="menu-drop2" ></div>
<div id="menu-drop3" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but the contents always go down and than immediately up :/

Comment: Ahh you want slidedown only if the the link is hovered and slideup on mouseleave? I just edit the fiddle in my answer. Check it out

Comment: thx, really for try to help me out here is a short example of what i want. But the submenu MUST have a width of 100%
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UHtH/)